# Change TabBar text color for selected item only (Xamarin.Forms iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm writing an app that has a TabBar. On iOS, I want to change the selected items' highlight to be green instead of this default blue.

[image: Blue Tabs]

I can use this line of code when creating the TabbedPage: 
`BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#27b286");`

This changes the Icon color as I want it to, but it also changes the textcolor on ALL tabs, not just the selected one (I want the selected tab text to be green).

[image: Green Tabs]

The TabPage code is:

```
 NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        if(Device.RuntimePlatform == "iOS")
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
            //BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#27b286");

            Children.Add(new CoinsPage() { Title = "Coins", Icon = "coins.png" });
            Children.Add(new PortfolioPage() { Title = "Portfolio", Icon = "portfolio.png" });
            Children.Add(new TrendingPage() { Title = "Trending", Icon = "trending.png" });
            Children.Add(new SettingsPage() { Title = "Settings", Icon = "settings.png" });
        }
```

How can I make ONLY the selected tab text color green?

Comment: What is the code you have now?

Comment: Edited post to include all code for generating my tabs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is intended to work like that. I think it would make sense because we are setting the *text* color and not the selected color or anything like that.

So, it seems there is no way to do this from pure Forms right now.

To set it for iOS, go into the `AppDelegate.cs` file and in your `FinishedLaunching` method add this line:

`UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Red;`

Of course, replacing the color with your own. It should now just be the selected item that is colored.

Comment: Is any way to android as well ?

Answer (score 3):

UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 122, 255);

```
        // Color of the tabbar background:
        UITabBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(247, 247, 247);

        // Color of the selected tab text color:
        UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(
            new UITextAttributes()
            {
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 122, 255)
            },
            UIControlState.Selected);

        // Color of the unselected tab icon & text:
        UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(
            new UITextAttributes()
            {
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(146, 146, 146)
            },
            UIControlState.Normal);
```

update this code in IOS file AppDelegate inside the method FinishedLaunching after 
 LoadApplication(new App());